# Mejor performance en consulta a BD Oracle

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework

Me interesa encontrar la manera de tener mejor performance en este escenario:

> 1. Tengo N procedimientos almacenados que deben retornar el resultado de consultas (`Select * from ...`).
> 2. Estos procedimientos almacenados los mapeo con Entity Framework. Ahora bien, para tener mejor performance, como me aconsejan retornar el resultado de la consulta:

En este momento se me viene a la cabeza 3 opciones

> 1. Retorno los resultados como cursor (En toda la red se rumorea que los cursores son malos) y así con Entity Framework los recupero como List de clases complejas autogeneradas
> 2. El resultado de la consulta lo convierto en XML y lo paso como un solo parámetro XML de salida, desde el Entity Framework recupero ese XML y lo deserealizo a un List de clases
> 3. Genero un algoritmo para poner todo el resultado en una sola cadena (o vector de cadenas) separado por PipeLine y desde Entity Framework lo recupero como cadena para luego, con otro algoritmo, llevarlo a un List clases

Bueno esas opciones se me vienen a la mente, ¿cual seria mejor en cuanto a tiempos proceso y performance?. ¿Existe alguna mejor opción que no esté considerando?

Nota: No puedo utilizar LINQ porque las consultas si o si deben ejecutarse en la base de datos y mediante un procedimiento almacenado retornar los resultados.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías intentar con el mismo Entity Framework para obtener la información sin caer en ningún método de los que mencionas. Podrías guiarte con el siguiente enlace a StackOverflow en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29013483/1617491

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero como indica en la pregunta estoy trabajando en Oracle (no SQL Server) y para hacer algo parecido a lo del enlace que proporcionas, se debe utilizar cursores en el lado de Oracle, y como todos dicen que los cursores son malos entonces quiero evaluar alternativas.

Comment: Entity Framework es capaz de conectarse a Oracle a través del Data Provider, talvez este artículo te sea de ayuda: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/articles/dotnet/implementar-aplicaciones-net-1924201-esa.html
Yo lo he utilizado sin problemas.

Comment: Mmmmmm no se si la pregunta esta mal redactada, el punto es que se conectarme se consumir SP se mapear se hacercreo que muchas cosas desde EF a Oracle, la pregunta es sobre performance, saber opiniones de performance en cuanto a las opciones que explique en la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción que nos salvo en mi trabajo fue dejar toda la información en una variable de sesión.

En tu caso, si fueran datos recurrentes podrías sólo asegurarte de agregar información nueva a la variable que asignes para guardar los datos.